# Laravel encrypt user email without breaking authentication

Tags: php, authentication, encryption, laravel-4

I want to have email addresses encrypted in the database. Using mutators I can encrypt and decrypt model properties for my laravel web-app.

The problem is that the email property is used for authentication. So using mutators for the email seems to totally break my app, presumably via Auth::check(), id(), login() etc.

I looked at writing a custom authentication driver but can't get it to work.

Simply I just want to know where to overload the model to add an encrypt on set and decrypt on get, that will be compatible with laravels authentication methods.

Comment: The problem is that Laravel uses a simple SQL where to find the user. To do what you want you'd have to fetch all users decrypt the email addresses and then search for the user by email. I don't think this can be done by just overriding a method...

Comment: Could you not do an encrypted email check. So get the input from the user (their email). encrypt their email, using the same method as the one stored in the database. Then compare these to values for the authentication?

Comment: @ChrisTownsend that would be the quick hack, but I wonder if it can be done while respecting laravels existing auth methods.

Comment: I'm wondering if you can extend the authentication class, by adding to this http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/extending#authentication and adding your own to the interface

Comment: Yeah already tried that couldn't get it to work at all sadly

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to implement some sort of [blind indexing](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql#solution-literal-search) in a custom `Auth` provider in addition to encryption.

There's a lot of ways to screw up such an implementation. Be sure to reference the CipherSweet documentation (especially its [security design](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/security) and [internals](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/internals)) to ensure your implementation does everything right.

Or, you can just use [CipherSweet](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com) to power your custom `Auth` provider and not worry about the cryptography implementation yourself.

Answer (score 0):

i know its too late but here is my implementation:
i somehow handled this in a dirty way.
before using laravel fortify i have to first get the user with its email using raw query to prevent triggering the model observer:

```
$operator = Operator::query()->whereBlind('email','operator_email_index', strtolower($request['email']))->first();
```

if operator exists then overwrite the email request and get the email directly from model:

```
if($operator) { $credentials['email'] = DB::table('operator_operators')->where('id',$operator->id)->first()->email; }
and then use the default Auth::Attempt method
$this->guard()->attempt( $credentials, $request->filled('remember') );
```

but with **fortify** you can easily overwrite the attempt with ***authenticateUsing*** method and prevent the extra queries.

here is my attemptLogin function:

```
 protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{

    $credentials = $this->credentials($request);
    $operator = Operator::query()->whereBlind('email','operator_email_index', strtolower($request['email']))->first();
    if($operator) {
        $credentials['email'] = DB::table('operator_operators')->where('id',$operator->id)->first()->email;
    }
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $credentials, $request->filled('remember')
    );
   
}
```